# Pandas groupby two columns, one by row and another by column

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I have a csv file that contains n rows of sales of houses.

| House | House_type | Sale_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Semi | 2010 |
| two | Flat | 2011 |
| three | bungalow | 2012 |
| four | Semi | 2013 |
| five | Semi | 2013 |

I want to groupby the data by House_type (flat, bungalow, semi) by sale_year (2010,2011,etc)  counts as columns.
So I'm trying to output the data in the below format.

| House_type | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Semi | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| Flat | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| bungalow | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

However, when I run the code, it returns both House_type and Sale_year as two columns.

```
house= housedata.groupby(["House_type", "Sale_year"])["Sale_year"].count()
house

House_type               Sale_year
Flat                     2011.0          1
bungalow                 2012.0          1
Semi                     2010.0          1
                         2013.0          2
```

How do I get pandas to output the data desired?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same using get_dummies method of pandas. It basically creates multiple columns for a categorical column and fills it with values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'House_type':['Semi','Flat','Bungalow','Semi','Semi'],'sale_year':[2010,2011,2012,2013,2013]})
df_final = pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['sale_year']).groupby('House_type').sum()
df_final
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_table` here:

```
result = pd.pivot_table(df, index='House_type', columns='Sale_year',
                        aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
```

It gives directly:

```
           House               
Sale_year   2010 2011 2012 2013
House_type                     
Flat           0    1    0    0
Semi           1    0    0    2
bungalow       0    0    1    0
```

You can format it a little if you want:

```
result.columns = result.columns.get_level_values(1).rename(None)
result = result.reset_index()
```

to finally get:

```
  House_type  2010  2011  2012  2013
0       Flat     0     1     0     0
1       Semi     1     0     0     2
2   bungalow     0     0     1     0
```